# How to convert a byte like string to normal bytes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, byte, imapclient

I've a problem during exception-handling with the [imapclient](https://github.com/mjs/imapclient)-library.

I tried to handle the LoginError like this:

```py
source = IMAPClient(host=args.source_server, port=args.source_port, ssl=not args.source_no_ssl)

try:
    print('Login source...'.format(args.source_user), end='', flush=False)
    source.login(args.source_user, args.source_pass)
    print('OK')

except exceptions.LoginError as e:
    print('ERROR: {}'.format(e))
    exit()
```

In case of exception i've got this:

```
Login source...ERROR: b'Invalid login'
```

I think The problem is, that `format` is calling the `__str__()`-method of the Exception-object and do not try to decode.

So the main question is who can i convert this string

```py
"b'Invalid login'"
```

to a normal bytes-object like this?

```py
b'Invalid login'
```

#### edit 1

@lenik
If i use `e.message.decode()` like this:

```py
try:
    print('Login source...'.format(args.source_user), end='', flush=False)
    source.login(args.source_user, args.source_pass)
    print('OK')
except exceptions.LoginError as e:
    print('ERROR: {}'.format(e.message.decode()))
    exit()
```

I've got an AttributeError:

```py
AttributeError: 'LoginError' object has no attribute 'message'
```

#### edit 2

@snakecharmerb

```py
try:
    print('Login source...'.format(args.source_user), end='', flush=False)
    source.login(args.source_user, args.source_pass)
    print('OK')
except exceptions.LoginError as e:
    print('ERROR: {}'.format(e.args[0].decode()))
    exit()
```

```py
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`imapclient`'s login method looks like [this](https://github.com/mjs/imapclient/blob/202398c3f2c5a85d2432a62800dfe363415f0111/imapclient/imapclient.py#L343):

```
def login(self, username, password):
    """Login using *username* and *password*, returning the
    server response.
    """
    try:
        rv = self._command_and_check(
            'login',
            to_unicode(username),
            to_unicode(password),
            unpack=True,
        )
    except exceptions.IMAPClientError as e:
        raise exceptions.LoginError(str(e))

    logger.info('Logged in as %s', username)
return rv
```

We can see that it calls `str` on `IMAPClientError`, so if `IMAPClientError` was created with a `bytes` instance as its argument then we end up with stringified bytes in `LoginError`<sup>*</sup>.

There are two ways to deal with this:

1. Access the original bytes via the exception's `args` tuple:

`msg = e.args[0].decode()`

2. Use [ast.literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) to convert the stringified exception:

`msg =  ast.literal_eval(str(e)).decode()`

Of the two approaches, I think (1) is better in this specific case, but (2) is more generally applicable when you have stringified bytes.

---

<sup>*</sup>Looking at the history of the [imaplib](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/imaplib.html) module on github, it looks as if it changed to explicitly decode error messages before raising errors from the authenticate command in Python 3.5.  So another solution might be to upgrade to Python 3.5+.

Comment: Thanks! Your first way does not work. `e.args[0]` is already the wrong string (see edit2).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to do this:

```
>>> a = b'invalid'
>>> a
b'invalid'
>>> a.decode()
'invalid'
```

?

---

ok, second take:

```
>>> import imaplib
>>> dir(imaplib.IMAP4.error)
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__getslice__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__module__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__setstate__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__unicode__', '__weakref__', 'args', 'message']
>>> imaplib.IMAP4.error.message
<attribute 'message' of 'exceptions.BaseException' objects>
```

seems like there should be a `message` there, because `LoginError` seems to be a descendant from `imaplib.IMAP4.error` according to the source: https://imapclient.readthedocs.io/en/2.1.0/_modules/imapclient/exceptions.html#LoginError

You might want to print `dir(e)` where you catch the exception to see what it has -- there should be something that get's converted by `__str__()` into a byte string.

---

Then again, there's a conversation about IMAP4 and IMAPClient library and catching the exceptions here: [Catching imaplib exception (using IMAPClient package) in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9759772/catching-imaplib-exception-using-imapclient-package-in-python)

Comment: In my case `"b'Invalid login'"` is not a byte, its a string. So it has no `decode()` only `encode()`. You can reproduce it with `str(b'some bytes')`. You'll get `"b'some bytes'"` what is actually a string.

Comment: Dear @Lukas -- I perfectly understand your problem. Just don't use `.format()` function before you `e.message.decode()` and you'll be golden =)

Comment: Hey lenik, i've modified the question. `e.message.decode()` is sadly not the solution :(

Comment: @Lukas Sorry for messed up answer, please, check the "second take"

Comment: `__cause__` is empty / `None`. Even if i do `except IMAPClient.Error as e` which is scripted in the conversation.

Output of `dir(e)`: `['__cause__', '__class__', '__context__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__setstate__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__suppress_context__', '__traceback__', '__weakref__', 'args', 'with_traceback']`.

Comment: Sorry, @Lukas -- the message should be somewhere there, but I could not figure out right now where exactly.

Answer (score 0):

1. for "b'xx'" --> b'xx'

```py
>>> s = "b'a'"
>>> eval(s)
b'a'
```

2. You can use `print('dir(e): {}'.format(dir(e)))` to see the attributes, or pickle it to a file and load it to ipython to parse.

Comment: Thanks. Your answer will work, but in this (and most other cases) `ast.literal_eval()` is more safe to use. See [Using python's eval() vs. ast.literal_eval()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15197673/using-pythons-eval-vs-ast-literal-eval).